# Auto Updating an Excel Filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I'm using excel 2010.

I have had a look at other "auto-update" and from what I saw they wanted you to type some information in to make it "refresh" the auto-update.

I have is two separate spread sheets and I have a table with filtered headings and I have a sheet with raw data. I have three columns on the table however I do not physically put any data into it. When the other spreadsheet is updated the references automatically place the values into my table.

For example the filter is set to "UK" but we still require to have all values there in case reference is needed as the people using this spreadsheet are not allowed to see the workings spread sheet due to confidentiality reasons.

Would make my life that little bit easier rather than un-filtering and re-filtering.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a question here. Are you trying to find an easy way to `Refesh` the view?

Comment: I don’t understand the question, either — but does the (F9) key do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Does the `Filter` -> `Reapply` command not do what you want? You can probably write a small VBA routine to run this command whenever the underlying data is updated.

Answer (score 1):

To repeat an action every 10 minutes:

When the workbook first opens, execute this code:

```
alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:10:00")
Application.OnTime alertTime, "MyMacro"
```

Then just have a macro in the workbook called "MyMacro" that will repeat it.

```
Public Sub EventMacro()
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter ' adjust to point to your filter
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:10:00")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventMacro"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste the following code into the worksheet with the data and update "Sheet1" to the sheet name with your auto-filter.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter 'update "Sheet1" to the name of your sheet with auto-filter

End Sub
```