# Reapply filter automatically every X minutes

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that uses the RTD server to update stock prices in real time.

I have a filter applied to the spreadsheet and would like to reapply it automatically.

I have found a solution to reapply the filter whenever the data is refreshed, but it doesn't seem to work with data refreshed by the RTD service.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter

End Sub
```

So I was wondering if its possible to reapply the filter every 5 minutes.

There's a solution to this problem in the link below, but I don't quite understand how to do this.

https://superuser.com/a/524527

Comment: I'm thinkng that you are missing something before your `ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter` 
 line to work like how you envision, maybe something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44974151/is-activesheet-autofilter-applyfilter-necessary-it-breaks-my-code-when-the-shee#:~:text=Only%20if%20you%20had%20applied%20some%20AutoFilter%20then,the%20active%20filter%2C%20you%20can%20then%20invoke%20Sheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What's missing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help you more than that. It's been 3-4 years since I last wrote VBA that applied filters. I just remember I couldn't apply a filter that wasn't first there. I thought the link I gave you would provide you with enough clues for you to figure it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting together
[your link](https://superuser.com/a/524527)
and the
[link by gns100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44974151/is-activesheet-autofilter-applyfilter-necessary-it-breaks-my-code-when-the-shee),
gets us the following VBA macro.
Call it by any name you like, and run it once to start the timer looping.

```
Public Sub EventMacro()
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData                    '<- keeps filter alive but shows all data
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter         '<- apply the filter
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")    '<- time = now + 5 minutes
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventMacro" '<- set timer
End Sub
```

(I have not tested this macro.)

Comment: It seems that my problem was something even simpler. I realized that I need to put the VBA code inside a module. For this reason it was not working. Your code works fine!